# python dictionary parsing using format and get new data

Tags: python

In the following code I make a deep copy of `_data` dictionary so that I don't change the original.
My question is how can I get the new version `v7` from the variable `my_str`
i.e, `my_str` should point me to `v7` and not `v6` anymore. I want to use the same variable `my_str` and not construct a new one.

```
_data = {"version":"v6"}
my_str = "{version}".format(**_data)
import copy 

new_data = copy.deepcopy(_data)
new_data["version"] = "v7"

print(my_str)  # I expected "v7" and not "v6" here
```

Comment: I think you are quite confusing some things... the way you set up my_dict makes it a string, not a dictionary

Comment: if you are getting the value from _data, that never changes, you would have to be using **new_data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is absolutely *no reason* you should have *'expected "v7" and not "v6"'*.

`my_dict` *isn't* a dictionary; it's a string:

```
>>> _data = {"version":"v6"}
>>> my_dict = "{version}".format(**_data)
>>> my_dict
'v6'
>>> type(my_dict)
<type 'str'>
```

There is no connection between `my_dict` and `_data`, and strings are *immutable* (can't be changed in-place). Even if there *was* some magic connection between the two, you have deliberately made `new_data` a copy of `_data` before updating it, which would have removed that connection.

There is *no way* to "update" `my_dict`, you have to create a new string from the new, altered dictionary:

```
my_dict = "{version}".format(**new_data)
```

or why not just access the value?

```
new_data['version']
```

Comment: As i told u already i do now want to construct a new string i just want tohack into the variable only

Comment: @Rajeev and as I've already told you, there is no way to do that. Is some part of my answer unclear?